# Why don't we affix the Mezuza unrolled?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, mezuzah

If the Mezuza were placed on the doorpost unrolled (in a suitable protective wrapping) one would be able to see the words and be inspired.

Why don't we do this?

Maybe it was because of the state of cleanliness in earlier times.

Is there anything to suggest that there is a deeper reason for the Mezuza to be rolled as opposed to unrolled?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for sharing this question. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. Hope to see you around.

Comment: "Maybe it was because of the state of cleanliness in earlier times."

Even if that were the case, I can assure you that, even in modern times, a good deal of damage can be done to an unfurled Mezuzah.

Do you want to know if, in fact, it must be rolled, as the common practice that you observe? Are you asking for the source for such a rule that it must be rolled?  Or are you asking for a conceptual/logical basis for such a rule?

Comment: If the Mezuza were put in a see through piece of laminted plastic, that would provide ample protection as well as the opportunity to see the writing. I am asking for the logic behind not having the mezuza unrolled. Hazoriz below says that the command is to write the Mezuza and not to see the words, different from Tzitzis. However, what would be the purpose of writing and then never seeing what is written?

Comment: @user9874 by knowing that it is there and what is written in them (we are commanded to learn torah; so we know what is written in them even without looking) there will still be a purpose (from the link in your comment below "At the root of the mitzvah [of the mezuzah] lies the purpose that it should remind a person about faith in G-d every time he [or she] enters the home or leaves it."), some have a custom to put there hand on it when they walk threw a doorway http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12051/what-is-the-origin-of-the-custom-to-kiss-a-mezuzah/12052

Comment: @user9874 you can say "However, what would be the purpose of writing and then never seeing what is written?" by the mitzvah of mila what is the purpose of the physical bris (covenant) if it is usual covered. or by a sotah what is the purpose of writing the parsha if you will then erase it. (maybe the bris is a bad example)

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83951/759

Answer (score 1):

"one would be able to see the words and be inspired."

Is by tzitis, but there is not command (from the holy one blessed be he) to see the mezuza the command is to write it and set it on your door/gate post

_---------------------

It might be because is needs to be a scroll

[Menachois 32b](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf#page=122)

> Rab Judah said in the name  of Samuel, If one wrote it like a letter,  it is invalid. Why?  — Because of the inference that is made by the expression ‘writing’, which is used here [in connection with the mezuzah] and also there in connection with the scroll. °10
>
> (°10) In connection  with the mezuzah it  is written (Deut. VI,9  ): And thou shalt  **write** them, and in  connection with the Book of  the Law  it is  written (Ex.  XVII, 14): **Write**  this for  a memorial  in the book;  as the  latter must  be written  with accuracy as  to spelling and upon  ruled lines, so the  mezuzah  too must be  written with accuracy and  upon ruled lines. Rashi also  suggests the inference  from  the writing  of’ a divorce (lit.,  ‘a book of  divorcement, v. Deut.  XXIV, 1), which must also be written with accuracy; but see Tosaf. s.v. vc,f

[Menachois 31b](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf#page=119)

> R. Helbo said, I have seen R. Huna rolling up the mezuzah beginning at ‘one’ and finishing at ‘hear’;

Comment: Thank you hazoriz for you answer. However, please see here http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/310885/jewish/The-Significance-of-Mezuzah.htm where there is a quote from Ibn Ezra that Mezuzah is like Tefillin and Tzitzis as a reminder for all the Mitzvos.Thank you for referencing the Gemoro in Menochos.

Comment: @user9874 i think the original is hear daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mahadurot/yesod-2.htm            והציצית [במדבר יה] למען תזכרו בראותו בכל רגע וככה וקשרתם וכתבתם (and the tzitzith (Numbers XV) ‘so that you should remember’ when you see it at every moment and so by "and tie (tefilin)" "and you should write (mezuzois)") it may be part of a point but i do not understand clearly the connection to what he wrote before.