# Kissing a doubtful scroll

Tags: minhag, tefilin, sefer-torah, mezuzah, kissing

There is a common custom to [kiss a mezuzah, or at least place one's hand on it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12051/9682). Likewise, there is a custom to [kiss Tefillin during davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38592/9682) and to [kiss the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35429/9682)

Should one kiss these objects if he is unsure if the scroll inside is kosher? This is barring the general question of whether one is allowed to use them if they are possibly passul.

Comment: Why not? It's just a cute gesture, if one wants to kiss it what's the problem? Like many questions if the answer would be that unsurprising there is no problem, it will likely be very difficult to prove since we will be stuck proving the negative. If you provide a specific reason why it might be a problem, we can try to evaluate whether that reason would apply.

Comment: Are you concerned about "Lifnei Iver"? ("misleading the blind")?

Comment: @mevaqesh the question was "Should one".